# Promise resolve has error in TypeScript because missed any type

Tags: javascript, typescript

I'm using gulp to compile TS files to JS and for this code:

```js
function Hello(): Promise<string> {
  return new Promise(resolve => {
    setTimeout(() => {
      resolve('Hello, World!');
    }, 3000);
  });
}
```

The compile has this error:

`error TS7006: Parameter 'resolve' implicitly has an 'any' type.`

That means, I should use `any` type like this:

`return new Promise((resolve: any) => {`

But why I should use `any` in this case? when I'm using `Promise<string>` to define the Promise ?

dependencies:

```
"dependencies": {
    "gulp": "^4.0.2",
    "gulp-typescript": "^6.0.0-alpha.1",
    "typescript": "^3.9.5"
  }
```

Thanks

Comment: Your code works for me in TS 3.9.3. I don't see any warnings, no need for `any`. I think the `Promise<string>` type gets propagated along properly.

Comment: @CertainPerformance It would be because TS bug in this version?

Comment: That sounds like a pretty unlikely regression, but it's not impossible. Probably something else is causing the inconsistency.

Comment: The error "Parameter 'resolve' implicitly has an 'any' type" means that you *shouldn't* use any. Try defining it as a `string` type and see if that helps.

Comment: If I understand the message correctly, it means TS doesn’t understand the `Promise` constructor and doesn’t know what type `resolve` is, so if anything you should help it out with `(resolve: (value: string) => void)`. Though the real solution would be to make TS properly understand `Promise`, which may be a setting related thing or a somehow missing type definition somewhere.

Answer (score 2):

It looks like TS compiler doesn't recognise the `Promise` type. The most likely reason for this is the lack or improper configuration. I would assume TS is compiling for `ES5` where promises are not defined. Try to update your `tsconfig.json` as described at [this page](https://www.typescriptlang.org/vo/tsconfig#lib). I.e. add the following to `tsconfig.json`

```
"compilerOptions": {
    "target": "ES6"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I've edited `gulpfile.js` and solved:

```js
gulp.task('ts', function () {
  return gulp.src('*.ts')
  .pipe(ts({
    noImplicitAny: true,
    outFile: 'output.js',
    target: 'ES6'
  }))
  .pipe(gulp.dest('./'));
});
```